# Can I display a subset of MS Teams messages?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'd like to somehow tag messages with some kind of identifier and then filter on that identifier when displaying those messages (via MS Graph API or similar). Is this possible with MS Teams?

Comment: Currently it is not possible to tag messages with some kind of identifier and then filter on that identifier. There is no API to group messages based on some identifier and then apply filter on these.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, thanks for letting me know. Unfortunately, this makes my MS Teams app idea impossible to implement. Hopefully this would be something they consider adding. Thanks again.

Comment: You can suggest this feature at [Microsoft feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).